# "Failed to get the compiler information for file ..." in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm running into this really bizarre error message in Android Studio. It shows up on top of my *native* code built using `ndk-build` through Gradle. The breakpoints and code stepping are working properly, but the code is absolutely littered with "errors" like "Can't resolve variable".

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Again, the code all runs correctly, it's just like the IDE doesn't seem to be able to resolve a whole bunch of the types. You can see the litany of errors on the right hand side. Basically every line is marked as an error even though it all compiles just fine. No idea what's going on!

Comment: Possible solutions 
1.Restart Android Studio

2. Clear cache

  File > Invalidate Caches /Restart > Invalidate caches | restart

3.Clean project

Comment: I think there are a whole *lot* of problems.

1. It seems there are a lot of bugs related to quoting/unquoting strings when setting cppFlags. I was trying to set the cppFlags using addAll, but when I did that it looked like the quotes got pulled right into the shell commands, causing them to fail. It looks like what happened is that that also botched the include directory statements, so the IDE wasn't able to resolve certain include files.

Comment: After that, it looks like running "Clean" on the project wasn't cleaning my externally-built NDK files -- only cleaning the Java side of things. So when I thought I was rebuilding the project it was just using old code over and over.

Comment: I've resorted to running `./gradlew externalNativeBuildDebug --debug` to build the code in the terminal rather than having Android Studio do it. This also allows me to see a bit more of the output. Unfortunately, I still can't see the actual ndk-build commands that gradle is executing. Which is ridiculous. I could run ndk-build myself, but then it'd be using the Application.mk file that gradle ignores.

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue in the end?

Comment: i think the issue i had was that i added `target_compile_definitions(myproject PUBLIC -Wno-unused-local-typedefs)` to my cmakelists file which resulted in `-D-Wno-unused-local-typedefs` being produced as a compile flag. removing it seems to resolve the issue. i also did a clean earlier so i initially thought that had messed something up. if someone can confirm that perhaps incorrect compile flags are the reason for this error message then i think this is probably the solution (or hint towards one).

Comment: @itchy23 I think to fix this one I had to manually delete the `build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local` directory. It seems to also help to run Refresh Linked C++ projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that performing the following operations fixed the issue:

1. Manually removing the directory `build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local`
2. Running `Refresh Linked C++ Projects`

Answer (score 1):

I had that in Android Studio 3.0 for MacOS. There was a space in my project's path (like "/Users/sergei/_Projects/Project-build/Project CPP/android/app") and it was an issue. So I just renamed "Project CPP" to "ProjectCPP" and an issue was fixed. I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only thing which helped was uninstalling the tool **ccache**.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the similar situation with the version 3.2.1 and cmake 3.6 on linux platform. I have spent some time investigating what could cause the problem and I started from clean, wizard generated project. As I copied feature by feature from my original project and inspected the Android Studio behavior, I have nailed it with the inclusion of the ccache tool in the compilation process. When I put:

```
# Add the ccache to the build system
option (USE_CCACHE "Koristiti ccache pri compiliranju ako je dostupan?" on)
find_program(CCACHE_FOUND ccache)
if(CCACHE_FOUND AND (USE_CCACHE))
    MESSAGE( STATUS "## Using CCache when building!")
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE ccache)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_LINK ccache)
else(CCACHE_FOUND AND (USE_CCACHE))
  MESSAGE( STATUS "## Not using CCache!")
endif(CCACHE_FOUND AND (USE_CCACHE))
```

inside CMakeLists.txt, everything builds fine, but Android Studio could not parse the code properly, specifically the headers within the angle brackets - system headers and all third party libraries.
When I switch off the ccache tool usage, everything works as expected.
I would like to use ccache since this tool gives an amassing productivity boost, especially during intensive refactoring, but unfortunately, I have to turn it off for now.